# Determining number of circles fitting in polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a large number of polygons for which I want to know the number of circles with a specific circumference fit inside of them. More specifically the center of the circles need to lie inside of the polygons, while the rest of the circle might also overlap the boundaries of the polygons.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The basic solution here is to generate a tessellation covering your feature of interest. I've done this in ArcGIS Pro, but ArcMap also has [Generate Tessellation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm), though it has fewer forms.

So here's a sample figure similar to @user30184's polygon:
[image: nominal figure]

The simplest way to do this is with a "Square" shape type option. I chose a size of "100", saved that to a new feature class, used [Feature to Point](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm) to make centroids, then generated a [Buffer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/buffer.htm) with a radius of "50", which got me here:
[image: square grid with circles]

When I did a [Select Layer By Location](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-location.htm) (with a "Have their center in" relationship), I wound up with 43 "inside" features:
[image: selected circles in square tessellation]

Note that the alignment just happens to be nearly optimal -- you'd be hard-pressed to alter the origin to get more than one additional feature into the selection set.

---

The procedure here is called "packing" and you can achieve a higher packing fraction if you use hexagons (the gaps on the diagonals are smaller).

Using the "Hexagon" shape type, with an area of "90" (empirically derived by keeping the buffer distance constant) and using the same Generate/Centroid/Buffer process, we now have 45 circles meeting your selection criteria, with two to three more possible with a slight origin shift:

[image: selected circles in Hexagon tessellation]

---

Now here's an example using the "Transverse hexagon" shape type (an option only available in Pro, but could be simulated in ArcMap by rotating the origin, or just doing the math in ArcPy) and the same "90" area and "5" buffer:
[image: selected circles in transverse hexagon tessellation]

There are only 44 circles selected in this figure, but shifting the origin just a little bit up and to the left could achieve another SEVEN (possibly eight)! This demonstrates the inherent advantage of hexagons in tessellation.

---

So the moral here is that there is variability in the output based on both shape size and origin, so any attempt to do this packing should be iterative (regular or random) or human-assisted. Also, hexagon centroids will give you an advantage, because they more naturally cover an area than circles based on square centroids.  You can also do the trig math backwards to get a bit more centroid density without circle overlap, which would net a bit more in the hexagon packing fraction.

---

PS: For the record, the side distance *s* for the hexagon to generate inscribed circles with radius *r* (touching at sides) is solved by the equation:

[image]

And since the hexagons in Generate Tessellation are generated by area, the area *A* of a hexagon is:
[image]

In Python that works out to:

```py
import math

diameter = 100
radius   = diameter * 0.5
side     = radius / math.sin(math.pi / 3.0)
hex_area = 1.5 * math.sqrt(3) * side * side
```

And the code to generate the base hexagon grid for a Cartesian spatial reference and an arbitrary 2km x 2km extent looks like:

```py
import arcpy

r = arcpy.SpatialReference(3968)
tess_shape = 'TRANSVERSE_HEXAGON' # or 'HEXAGON'
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\packed_circles\cartesian.gdb"
extent = '-1000 -1000 1000 1000'
subscript  = 1

print("Generating hexagons with side {:.6f}...".format(side))
arcpy.management.GenerateTessellation(
    Output_Feature_Class="hexagons{:d}".format(subscript),
    Extent=extent,
    Shape_Type=tess_shape,
    Size="{:f} SquareMeters".format(hex_area),
    Spatial_Reference=sr.exportToString()
)
print("Generating centroids...")
arcpy.management.FeatureToPoint(
    in_features="hexagons{:d}".format(subscript),
    out_feature_class="centroids{:d}".format(subscript),
    point_location="CENTROID"
)
print("Generating circles (radius {:.1f})...".format(radius))
arcpy.analysis.Buffer(
    in_features="centroids{:d}".format(subscript),
    out_feature_class="circles{:d}".format(subscript),
    buffer_distance_or_field="{:.1f} Meters".format(radius),
    line_side="FULL",
    line_end_type="ROUND",
    dissolve_option="NONE",
    dissolve_field=None,
    method="PLANAR"
)
```

*Note: I'm working on a Python toolbox to locate an optimal solution, but since there are an infinite number of potential solutions, it will need to involve heuristics and iteration (in both origin and orientation). I'll post a second answer when I have a solution.*

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, instead of circles you can use as well squares or just equidistant points.

[image]

One option is to create a polygon grid that covers the geometries https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/data-reviewer/creating-a-polygon-grid-using-selected-features.htm and select the cells whose centroids are within the geometry. Most GIS programs have tools for all these steps so the same method can be used with ArcMAP, QGIS, OpenJUMP etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, that´s nearly the solution i´m looking for. Ideally the solution should be optimized for the maximum number of possible circles within a polygon, but i don´t think there is a solution for that, without writing a script, right?

Comment: Offset point rows, as in a `HEXAGON` or `TRANSVERSE_HEXAGON` solution using [GenerateTessellation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/generatetesellation.htm), would generate a higher packing coefficient.