Fill polygon with circles
Essentially, I need these polygons to be circle packed with a varying degree of circles, using the red ones as an example.
The green polygons are represented as a canopy layer for a topology report. The circles will ulitmately be the height of the trees.
Ideally a way to put X amount of circle within the polygon and pack it would be sufficient. Overlapping to a small degree doesn't matter nor would size be an issue. But as you can see the smaller shapes would require smaller circles.


What is the purpose of the circles?

And what is the rule behind the circle size/placement? E.g., why is one bigger than the others, why do two overlap, why are two neighbouring circles not touching at all, why is one circle intersecting the canopy layer ...

There are an infinite number of ways to pack a polygon with circles, even if you limit all the circles to a single size, and even if you arbitrarily limit the packing to closely touching offset rows, as in a hexagon tessellation. Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/461597/determining-number-of-circles-fitting-in-polygon-using-arcmap

It's an iterative process:

find the Maximum Inscribed Circle
if it's too big, divide the circle to smallest circles,

rinse and repeat in your remaining area until you've covered your aoi
put approrpriate barriers for when to stop (eg minimum radius)

-- n

Iterative, NP and probably NP-Hard.
